# XLST - Count characters then next line XML

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt, count

Good Day, Sorry I'm still new in XML-XLST environment.
I have a stylesheet and something like have an if-else statement which it will count the characters/string for that attributes if is > 100 it will move to the next line. Is it possible?

Here is the code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Orders/Remark/text()"/></font></td>
```

Code Updated:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@/Orders/Remark/text() &gt; 100">
<xsl:value-of select="/Orders/Remark/text()"/></font></td>
</xsl:if>
```

**For More Explanation**
I really don't know how I will execute this codes, I only really want is 
if the of this `<xsl:value-of select="/Orders/Remark/text()"/>` if the strings is greater than 100, the exceeded (101 and so on...)  strings will be go the next line.

**Sample Picture:**

This is the output right now that if the remarks string is greater 100.

[image]

What I want is something like this if Remarks string is greater 100 the next string will go to the next line.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code posted supposed to do? I can't see any attempt to count and no attribute selector expression i.e `@attribute_name` involved there..

Comment: @har07 I already updated the code, I don't have any idea how will execute the codes. What I really want is the value of `<xsl:value-of select="/Orders/Remark/text()"/>` if it is > 100 the other characters will go to the next line. Thank you.

Comment: @har07: Here sir. Thanks 

`<Orders>
  some attributes are here not connected to remarks...
  <Remark>
    <Remarks>12345678901231</Remarks>
  </Remark>`

Comment: @har07, Thank you sir, but how can I code if the string count 105 and I want the 5 will go to the next line? Thanks again sir!

Comment: If you could post an [MCVE] i.e minimal XML sample, minimal XSLT attempt, and the actual output you want to get, it will be a lot easier to answer

Comment: @har07: Okay, I will wait sir. Thank you.

Comment: Waiting will not make your question any clearer... If I am guessing correctly, you want to split text into lines of maximum length. If so, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068953/xslt-split-string-on-every-nth-character-in-loop/34071485#34071485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to output value of `/Orders/Remark/text()` only if its length is over `100`, then this can be done without `xsl:if`. You can use XPath predicate expression (`[...]`) to filter the `text()` nodes to those satisfy the minimum length requirement, for example :

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Orders/Remark/text()[string-length(.) &gt; 100]"/>
```

Comment: So if the string-length is 101 it will  not show up right?

Comment: The code currently do the opposite: the string will show up if its length is 101 or more. Try `&lt;=` if you want otherwise

Comment: so if the code is `&lt;= 100` then how can I go to the next line the remaining strings? thank you sir.

Comment: XSLT execution will go to the next line (in the same `xsl:template`) automatically after the code in this answer executed. So I don't understand what you asked in your comment. As I've suggested very early in the comment to your question, post [MCVE] and people will understand what you're trying to do precisely without you have to explain much.

Comment: I already update my thread with some picture. Thanks.